# Half-normal distribution: Distribution of absolute difference between two points sampled from a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I have a normally distributed random variable $X$. I sample two points $x_1$ and $x_2$, and I am interested in the absolute difference between these two sampled points: $d=|x_2-x_1|$.

I repeat this $N$ times collecting $N$ pairs of points, giving me absolute differences of $d_1, d_2, ... d_N$.

Is it possible to say anything about the distribution of $d$? Specifically, I would like to construct a confidence interval on $d$, i.e. "with $1-\alpha$ confidence, $d$ falls within this interval."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A sum of two normals is normal. The variance doubles. The mean is going to be zero. The absolute difference is going to be like an absolute value of a normal, i.e. the density function will be something like: $f(d)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{d^2}{4\sigma^2}}$

Obviously, the domain is $d\in[0,\infty)$

As @A.Donda pointed out, it's a half-normal distribution, with properly a plugged variance.

You observe X, which means that you can estimate its variance $\hat\sigma^2$ by using usual estimator such as $\hat\sigma^2=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2$, where the mean estimator is usual $\bar x =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

The variance of d can be easily computed using [half-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) distribution properties: $\hat\sigma_X=2\hat\sigma^2(1-\frac{2}{\pi})$

Comment: The distribution of the absolute value of a normally distributed RV is also known as half-normal distribution, which is a (scaled) $\chi_1$ distribution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution

Comment: Something is wrong with this answer as $f(d)$ should be nil when $d$ is negative. Maybe you should add something like $1_{d > 0}$ to your answer.

Comment: @ThePawn, the domain is $[0,\infty]$

Comment: That is why it would be clearer to write $f(d) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(-\frac{d^2}{2 \sigma^2})1_{d > 0}$.

Comment: @ThePawn, right, but I hate this indicator function notation which mathematicians seem to love

Comment: It is now fine when you explicitly specify the domain.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I have a follow up question. Say I do not know $\sigma$ of the original distribution $X$. Can I say anything about the distribution of $d$ in this case, using some estimate of the population standard deviation obtained from my samples?

Comment: @Max, what are you observing: X or d?

Comment: I suppose I am making two observations of $X$ then computing $d$ as the absolute difference between the observations. My application is this: I would like to be able to say "this measurement tool makes repeatable observations of property $X$ - with 95% confidence, two repeated measurements will be within some distance $d$ of one another". Does this make any sense or am I totally off track?

Comment: @Max, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

*Comment:*  Reality check, using simulation, on @Aksakal's (+1) solution.
With a million iterations we can expect
about 2 or 3 place accuracy for the SD.
Let $\mu = 100, \sigma=2.$

```
set.seed(2022)
d = replicate(10^6, abs(diff(rnorm(2, 100, 2))))
sd(d)
[1] 1.703695   # aprx SD of d from simulation
sqrt(8*(1 - 2/pi))
[1] 1.705005   # exact SD of d

hist(d, prob=T, col="skyblue2",  
      main="Half-normal Dist'n")
 curve(exp(-x^2/16)/(2*sqrt(pi)), 
       add=T, col="brown", lwd=2)
```

[image]